# Should you average loss and accuracy across epochs or steps?

Tags: loss-functions, training-error

In a typical training loop what is the correct way to report and average metrics like  accuracy and loss. Should you maintain a running average through the whole process or reset it each epoch. What is the impact of doing either on and is one more correct?

```
train_loss = 0
num_samples = 0
for i in range(EPOCHS):
 for batch in dataset:
   loss = model(batch)
   train_loss += loss
   num_samples += len(batch)
   print("training loss: ", train_loss / num_samples)
```

versus

```
for i in range(EPOCHS):
 train_loss = 0
 num_samples = 0
 for batch in dataset:
   loss = model(batch)
   train_loss += loss
   num_samples += len(batch)
   print("training loss: ", train_loss / num_samples)
```